# Access requires a username and password

Tags: iis, hosting, asp.net, windows

Access requires a username and password

***Warning: This server is requesting that your username and password be sent in an insecure manner (basic authentication without a secure connection)***

I am getting this above message. I have hosted a website in godaddy hosting space. But when i run it.. it is prompt for User name and Password (above message). I am not using windows authentications in my website.... Moreover, i have test my website code on testing server....it never prompts for this message unless Integrated Windows Authentication is checked.
Any help is appreciated..
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You've got it the wrong way around. Using Basic Authentication without a secure connection (HTTPS) **will** result in the credentials being passed unencrypted over the net. You would **not** get this message with Integrated Windows Authentication (and I'm sure you never did). If you don't get the message on the test server using basic authentication, it might be because the browser detects that the server is on a local network.

You can do one of two things: change to integrated windows authentication or activate SSL. For an web site exposed to the internet, integrated windows authentication is not recommended, since it tends not to work propertly across proxies.

**Edit:** The site seems to use forms authentication - ie. user name and password entered in fields in a page. In such a scenario, the authentication is performed by the web application, and not left to the web server. In other words, the server should be set up with no authentication - not basic, not integrated windows, but anonymous access.

Keep in mind that with forms authentication, credentials will also be passed unencrypted over the net unless SSL is activated.

Comment: Hi

This is link where i posted my code...
http://www.sigell.com

Why it is prompting for user name and password there?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem but then discovered that the IP address assigned to the web server was same as one of the wireless router in our intranet. I changed the IP address of the web server and the problem was resolved.